# Selenium C# reading data from Excel for data driven testing Based On SheetName

Tags: c#, excel, selenium-webdriver, junit

I am trying to perform Data driven testing by loading client codes from Excel file to login and perform other operation.I am trying to iterate my test for all clients in the User_Name column. I only need to read Data From SheetName, right now i have Contstant SheetName (i,e sheet1), wanted to add SheetName Parameter

Any help with this would be much appreciated thank you.

I am using ExcelDataReader v3.4.0, ExcelDataReader.DataSet v3.4.0, selenium Webdriver v3.11.0

My Excel Generic Code is Below:

````
```
    using ExcelDataReader;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace MyDemoAutomation
    {
     public class ExcelUtil
     {
     public DataTable ExcelToDatable(string fileName)
        {
        // open file and returns as stream

        FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        // create openXmlReader via ExcelReaderFactory
        IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        //Set the first row as column name
      var result1 = excelReader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
            {
            ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                {
                UseHeaderRow = true
                }
            });
 
        // Return as dataset
        DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
        // Get all tables
        DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
        // Store in Database
        DataTable resultTable = table["Sheet1"];
````

*Here instead Sheet 1 i Want to Pass SheetName as Parameter(In Existing Code How can i Add*
// return
return resultTable;

```
        }

         List<DataCollection> dataCol = new List<DataCollection>();
         public void PopulateInCollection(string fileName)
        {

        DataTable table = ExcelToDatable(fileName);
        for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
            {

            for (int col = 0; col < table.Columns.Count; col++)
                {

                DataCollection dtTable = new DataCollection()
                    {
     


                    rowNumber = row,
                    colName = table.Columns[col].ColumnName,
                    colValue = table.Rows[row - 1][col].ToString()
                    };
                dataCol.Add(dtTable);

                }
            }
        }

        public string ReadData(int rowNumber, string columnName)
        {
        try
            {
            // Retriving data using LINQ to reduce much of iterations
            string data = (from colData in dataCol
                           where colData.colName == columnName && colData.rowNumber == rowNumber
                           select colData.colValue).SingleOrDefault();

            return data.ToString();
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
            return null;
            }
        }

        internal class DataCollection
        {
        public int rowNumber { get; internal set; }
        public string colName { get; internal set; }
        public string colValue { get; internal set; }
        }
    }
```

}

and the TestClass:

```
        [Test]
        public void DataDrivenTest_FromExcel()
        {

        Driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
        ExcelUtil util = new ExcelUtil();
        util.PopulateInCollection(@"C:\dan\AutomationTest\TestData\test.xlsx");
        Driver.FindElement(By.Id("contentPlaceholder_txtClientCode")) 
       .SendKeys(util.ReadData(i));
    
         Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='btnLogin']")).Click();
         Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//* 
              [@id='tabContent0']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")).Click();
        Driver.FindElement(By.Id("contentPlaceholder_txtcloseButton")).Click();
    
          Driver.Quit

           }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<DataCollection> dataCol = new List<DataCollection>();
public void PopulateInCollection(string fileName, string sheetName)
{
    DataTable table = ExcelToDataTable(fileName, sheetName);
    //Iterate through the rows and columns of the Table
    for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <= table.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            Datacollection dtTable = new Datacollection()
            {
                rowNumber = row,
                colName = table.Columns[col].ColumnName,
                colValue = table.Rows[row - 1][col].ToString()
            };
            //Add all the details for each row
            dataCol.Add(dtTable);
        }
    }
}

public DataTable ExcelToDaTable(string fileName, string sheetName)
{
    // open file and returns as stream

    FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    // create openXmlReader via ExcelReaderFactory
    IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    //Set the first row as column name
    var result = excelReader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
    {
        ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
        {
            UseHeaderRow = true
        }
    });

    // Return as dataset
    DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
    // Get all tables
    DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
    // Store in Database
    DataTable resultTable = table[sheetName];
    return resultTable;
}
```

---

#End

//Define this first
util.PopulateInCollection("fileName", "sheetName");

//Reading from excel file
util.ReadData(rowNumber, columnName)

Let's go through the code step-by-step to understand how it works:

1. `List<DataCollection> dataCol = new List<DataCollection>();`
   Here, a new List of `DataCollection` objects is created and named `dataCol`. This list will store the data read from the Excel file.
2. `public void PopulateInCollection(string fileName, string sheetName)`
   This method takes two parameters: `fileName` (the path to the Excel file) and `sheetName` (the name of the sheet from which the data should be read).
3. `DataTable table = ExcelToDataTable(fileName, sheetName);`
   This line calls the method `ExcelToDataTable` to read the data from the Excel file specified by `fileName` and `sheetName` into a DataTable object named `table`.
4. `for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)`
   This for loop iterates over each row in the DataTable `table`.
5. `for (int col = 0; col <= table.Columns.Count; col++)`
   This nested for loop iterates over each column in the DataTable `table`.
6. `Datacollection dtTable = new Datacollection() { ... };`
   Inside the nested loop, a new `Datacollection` object is created and initialized with the row number, column name, and column value for each cell in the DataTable.
7. `dataCol.Add(dtTable);`
   The `Datacollection` object created in the previous step is added to the `dataCol` List, effectively populating the list with data from the Excel file.

Now, let's take a look at the `ExcelToDataTable` method:

1. `public DataTable ExcelToDaTable(string fileName, string sheetName)`
   This method takes the same parameters as before, `fileName` and `sheetName`, and is responsible for reading the data from the Excel file.
2. `FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);`
   This line opens the Excel file specified by `fileName` in read mode and creates a FileStream named `stream`.
3. `IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);`
   Using the `stream`, this line creates an instance of `IExcelDataReader` using `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader`. The `IExcelDataReader` interface provides methods to read data from Excel files.
4. `var result = excelReader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration() { ... });`
   The `AsDataSet` method reads the data from the `excelReader` into a DataSet object named `result`. It uses an `ExcelDataSetConfiguration` object to specify the configuration options for reading the data. In this case, the configuration is set to use the first row as column names.
5. `DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();`
   This line is redundant and should be removed, as `result` was already assigned in the previous step.
6. `DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;`
   The `Tables` property of the DataSet `result` provides access to the collection of DataTable objects contained in the DataSet. The `DataTableCollection` is assigned to the variable `table`.
7. `DataTable resultTable = table[sheetName];`
   This line retrieves the specific DataTable from the `table` collection based on the `sheetName` provided as an argument.
8. `return resultTable;`
   The method returns the DataTable containing the data from the specified sheet in the Excel file.

Overall, the `PopulateInCollection` method reads the data from the Excel file into a DataTable using the `ExcelToDataTable` method and then iterates over each cell in the DataTable. For each cell, it creates a `Datacollection` object with the row number, column name, and cell value, and adds it to the `dataCol` List. The end result is that `dataCol` contains the data from the Excel file in the form of `Datacollection` objects.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Comment: It's not clear why this answer would be a solution to the issue opener has.